# adding styles a word using javascript but avoid links

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add style a Word using JavaScript, but when runs it replace **links** and **alt** where find the Word. Look the script.

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/Amaru/g, '<span class="styleam">amaru</span>');
```

and the styles

```
    .styleam{
font-family:"Inder",Century Gothic,HelveticaNeue-Light,Helvetica Neue Light,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,Lucida Grande,sans-serif !important;
;color:#0c5d4e;text-transform:lowercase;
 }
```

thanks you so much.

Comment: Can you post the HTML?

Comment: @Wowsk it isnt posible, i am working on a page that means has too much HTML, you can check the page amaru.guru

Comment: Well, you are running `replace()` on the whole content of your page. I think it would be better to target specific elements.

Comment: @Ciprianis i know, but the problema is, are too many words

Answer (score 0):

you can write

```
<span id="something">amaru</span>
```

and apply class using javascript like

```
var d = document.getElementById("something");
d.className += " styleam";
```

Comment: Thanks but i need chage a many words at same time, if no that works

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
var t = document.body.children;
var g = 'script';
[].filter.call(t, function(el) {
    return el !== g;
}).forEach(function(dd) {
    var j = dd.innerHTML.replace(/Amaru/g,'<span class="styleam">amaru</span>');
    dd.innerHTML = j;
});
```

Comment: thanks but no, coz even take LINKS or ALT where the Word **amaru** appears